# Error (Xcode): Interface Builder can’t determine the type of “LaunchScreen.storyboard”. This may be due to a missing SDK

Tags: flutter

I was able to run my app on iOS simulator but now I connot do it.
I get error message when I run my app.
“Error (Xcode): Interface Builder can’t determine the type of “LaunchScreen.storyboard”. This may be due to a missing SDK.”

I have tried flutter clean already, but it does not help to run my app correctly.

I want to run my app on iOS simulator correctly